# Кто-нибудь пользуется GSS?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Расскажите кто пользуется и в чем основной смысл, я так понял, что можно логику отображения писать на CSS. Увидел у Google, но инфы очень мало, на русском вообще нет.

Comment: Речь об этом? [gridstylesheets](https://gridstylesheets.org/) и [vimeo](https://vimeo.com/91393694)

Comment: Какие возможности предоставляет GSS, чем он лучше CSS или Less

Comment: Да, об этом, я увидел у Гугла файлы с расширением gss

Comment: @LEQADA, вопрос хороший - пусть остаётся. Хотя, мне кажется маловероятным, что этим кто-то пользовался... Не посмотрев видео сказать сложно. Но мне пока некогда его смотреть, к сожалению... Уже запас ссылок на просмотр накопился...

Answer (score 1):

GSS - это реализации технологии [Badros & Borning's Constraint Cascading Style Sheets](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/constraints/web/ccss-uwtr.pdf). Судя по количеству звезд на [гитхабе](https://github.com/gss/engine), используют ее еще как.
Эта штука позволяет гибко управлять лэйаутами с помощью относительных правил для элементов. Например, отцентрировать элемент в другой элемент одной строчкой:

```
#thing[center] == #other[center]
```

В качестве наглядного примера я бы посмотрел исходники [сайта GSS](https://gridstylesheets.org/), он как раз использует эту технологию.

Кстати, для `Sublime Text` [точно есть плагин](https://github.com/rhysbrettbowen/gss.sublime-package)

Comment: Очень слабый туториал, может кто разобрался напишет свой на русском